# deploying a rails project to a remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

is it possible to deploy a rails project to a remote server using FileZilla ? the server is running nginx/1.4.6 (ubuntu)

if no what is the best way to deploy the project if there is already a running version !

Comment: where is the server that you want to push to? is it like a AWS? or a heroku?

Comment: You should consider using [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question yes, the code needs to be up, so FTP should do the trick. You might need to restart nginx to pick up the changes, usually touching a restart.txt is enough, but that's particular to your setup.

Is this the best way? Possibly not!

Others suggested capistrano and that would be a good fit for a server you maintain, or go Heroku (or similar) service for a simpler setup.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying a Rails app is a tough job. There is always the easy way (heroku) however shared servers don't deal well with rails. Theoretically you can but usually this shared servers have really outdated ruby and rails versions and are absolutely useless. And you can try to connect via ssh and try to update it but i doubt you will be able to do that. So... If you are a rails developer i can suggest.

1- For small apps run Heroku (easy and free) however cost grows like hell with the app's growth

2- If you're thinking about developing big apps get a dedicated server (you can get cheap ones for 5€/month) and configure it as u would for your computer except when you run rails you run it in production.

3- Trust me... i fought enough Rails and shared servers and i quit... I just gave up